# Python3, Pandas, Extract associated Data from Dataframe to dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've been working with a CSV file. I created a dataframe based on the file:
[image: csv_file_before_changes]

and added index names. and printed the dataframe (with added index names):

[image: Print_Output_data2]

```
#Here is the code before failed computations.
import pandas as pd
import csv

colName = ['carIndex', 'carMake', 'Floatnum']
data2 = pd.read_csv('cars.csv', names=colName)
print(data2)
```

I have been trying to extract data to reach my goals although I have had some difficulty. My goals are as follows:

1. extract data and write alphabetical Dictionary with "carIndex" as key and a value of 0 - 2 (associated with Car A - C)
2. extract data and write alphabetical Dictionary with "carMake" as key and a value of 0 - 1 (Associated With Make X & Y)
3. Create (three) key-value pairs for the make "X" & "Y"'s values (associated with carIndex A-C) If a value doesn't exist the index should be None. append all three to a list of lists.
4. Finally take all three fields (First Dictionary, Second Dictionary, List-of-lists) and add them to a tuple for exportation

### Anyone have suggestions for how I can extract the data as I want? Thanks in advance.

In Response to:

Will you please add two things to the question: 1. a text version of your dataframe (preferrably from print(df.to_dict())), and 2. a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

1. print(data2.to_dict()) (outputs) --> {'carIndex': {0: 'Car C', 1: 'Car A', 2: 'Car B', 3: 'Car B', 4: 'Car A'}, 'carMake': {0: ' Make X', 1: ' Make X', 2: ' Make X', 3: ' Make Y', 4: ' Make Y'}, 'Floatnum': {0: 2.0, 1: 2.5, 2: 1.5, 3: 4.0, 4: 3.5}}
2. Output Tuple I want: print(my_tup) (outputs) -->
   ({'Car A': 0, 'Car B': 1, 'Car C': 2}, {'Make X': 0, ' Make Y': 1}, [[2.5, 3.5], [1.5, 4.0], [1.0, None]])

Comment: Will you please add two things to the question: 1. a text version of your dataframe (preferrably from `print(df.to_dict())`), and 2. a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: @user17242583 
I added the text version of the dataframe in the form of a dictionary.
And next added my desired output tuple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract data and write alphabetical Dictionary with "carIndex" as key and a value of 0 - 2 (associated with Car A - C)

```
sorted =  data2.sort_values('carIndex').drop_duplicates(subset='carIndex').reset_index()
carIndexDict = sorted['carIndex'].to_dict()
```

This will output

```
{0: 'Car A', 1: 'Car B', 2: 'Car C'}
```

Extract data and write alphabetical Dictionary with "carMake" as key and a value of 0 - 1 (Associated With Make X & Y)

Use the same strategy:

```
sorted =  data2.sort_values('carMake').drop_duplicates(subset='carMake').reset_index()
carMakeDict = sorted['carMake'].to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{0: 'Make X', 1: 'Make Y'}
```

To make the list:

```
carIndexes = carIndexDict.values()
carMakes = carMakeDict.values()

full_list = []

for idx in carIndexes:
  idx_search = data2.loc[df['carIndex'] == idx]
  car_list = []
  for make in carMakes:
    make_search = idx_search.loc[idx_search['carMake'] == make]
    if not make_search.empty:
      car_list.append(make_search['Floatnum'].iloc[0])
    else:
      car_list.append(None)

  full_list.append(car_list)
```

Outputs:

```
[[2.5, 3.5], [1.5, 4.0], [2.0, None]]
```

And finally the tuple:

```
myTuple = (carIndexDict, carMakeDict, full_list)
```

Outputs:

```
({0: 'Car A', 1: 'Car B', 2: 'Car C'}, {0: 'Make X', 1: 'Make Y'}, [[2.5, 3.5], [1.5, 4.0], [2.0, None]])
```